Access to wwwroot folder denied in dotnet MAUI Blazor-Hybrid application
I have a dotnet 8 MAUI Blazor Hybrid application and I need to save a file in the wwwroot/videos folder.
Everything works fine on my machine in DEBUG and RELEASE running through Visual Studio and when running the installed application.
However, after publishing in RELEASE and giving the application to a client, they are getting
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\xxxxx_1.0.6.0_x64__p0vm33n94x0y0\wwwroot\videos\xxxxx.mp4' is denied. at System.IO.FileSystem.CopyFile(String sourceFullPath, String destFullPath, Boolean overwrite) at ...
I've verified the destination folder exists, the file to be copied exists and I can read from that folder.  I just can't copy into that folder on their machine.

It helps always to remember the primary purpose of a .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid app.

By using .NET MAUI and Blazor together, you can reuse one set of web UI components across mobile, desktop, and web.

Coming to you question
You mentioned

I need to save a file in the wwwroot/videos

Fist of all this not a Blazor server app. In your case you're building a native windows application.
In context with MAUI Blazor Hybrid app, the wwwroot is just a folder that consists of all static web assets (scripts, CSS files, images, and other files) required by your Razor components. These assets are packaged with the application during deployment and are meant to remain static.
You can't write anything to this folder or any other folder inside the installation path C:\Program Files\WindowsApps in runtime.
In development, the app runs from a writable directory, which doesn't have these restrictions.
To save files during runtime, you have follow the same way we do in normal .NET MAUI app. For example
var videosPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "videos");
Directory.CreateDirectory(videosPath); 

var destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(videosPath, "your-video-file.mp4");
File.Copy(sourceFilePath, destinationFilePath, overwrite: true);

